# Changes need to be done in files to deploy axis2.war

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

I need to deploy axis2.war in tomcat. In which files(web.xml and server.xml??) and where in those files I should make changes in order to deploy the axis2 war in tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 war can be deployed as a web app itself, please refer below blog for deploying axis2 on tomcat.

http://jayalalk.blogspot.com/2014/01/writing-axis2-services-and-deploying-in.html

Comment: it is failing at 3rd step in your blog. If we just copy the axis2 folder in webapps of tomcat then how can it work? don't we need to include anything in web.xml of tomcat? how this axis2 gets deployed automatically if we start the tomcat server after we put the application i.e. axis2 in tomcat webapps?

Comment: Please make sure, you download war distribution (not binary distribution) as mentioned in steps. finally you will see <tomcat_home>\webapps\axis2   folder, so inside this folder there are 4 folders (axis2-web,META-INF,org,WEB-INF) , so tomcat will use WEB-INF folder web.xml for deployment as a webmodule